# how to pass variable to adf execute pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, execute

I have Created an ADF pipeline which calls a child pipeline (Via execute pipeline).
How can I pass the value of variable(start_date and end_date) to execute child pipeline(calls Databricks notebook ).
I am unable to get the variable value inside execute child pipeline(has databricks notebook).
Please find the pipeline image as below
[image]

and the child pipeline inside execute pipeline is below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the parameters in Parent and Child pipeline. In the child pipeline you will have to pass the parent pipeline's parameter value

For Ex. your parameter name in parent in ParaParent1 and the same parameter in child is ParaChild1. The value of ParaParent 1 should be the actual value and value of child parameter ParaChild1 would be @pipeline().parameters.ParaParent1

Please refer to a similar article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/175485/passing-parameters-in-the-execute-pipeline-activit.html